Blue light filter for Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm?
Is there a blue light filter available for Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm?
f.lux's website directs us to here: https://github.com/xflux-gui/fluxgui, where we are warned "XFLUX DOES NOT WORK ON MOST MODERN SYSTEMS". So I assumed it wouldn't work.
I am a beginner to computers so I would appreciate your assuming as little knowledge as possible.

what is the specific problem that you have?

@jsotola I would like to filter blue light in the way that f.lux and other such programs do but I don't know if there is a blue light filter that works for Pi 5.

wouldn't that be dependent on the Linux distribution that you are using?

@jsotola That makes sense. I have updated the question.

maybe this works ... https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gammastep
